# How do I link my sound files to my buttons?

Tags: android, button, audio, media-player, media

I have the image buttons inserted, i know how to get images to them, and I have the soundfiles in the `res>raw` folder.

How do I link these sounds to each button? I'm guessing something with the mediacontroller button? (i'm in the graphical layout)

Additional questions:

- Do I have to make edits in both the main.xml and .java file?
- Is there anything I need to do to the manifest or r.java file?
- Does anybody know of some great learning resources out of the ordinary? (i've already scoped out about every vid tutorial on Google dev page)

Answer (score 1):

The best learning resource is the Android Examples attached to the SDK.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Shows example code of what you want to do, all you need to do is adapt it slightly.

Comment: ok cool great resource, Thanks! Running into some problems, but working on it!

Answer (score 0):

then you probably read this documentation about [MediaPlayers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html). You don't need MediaButtons, just apply a simple OnClickListener on each Button.
No need to change XML for this, neither the manifest. Just apply OnClickListeners to them.
You can do to R.Java whatever you want as it gets overridden all the time you change something in XML, copy a new Resource or whatever.

EDIT due to comment:
So if you have a RootView like LinearLayout you could call

```
LinearLayout yourRootLayout = findView....
int count = yourRootLayout.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    View v = yourRootLayout.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof Button){
        Button b = (Button)v;
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

You just have to let your Activity implement OnClickListener and make a switch in onClick(View v) on Button.getId() and compare it with your R.id.YOUR_IDENTIFIER

Edit2:
I don't know exactly what count it will return you. just check it. I assume that it can either be only direct Childs, or all Childs. 
if it is every Child you can be happy and just switch the LinearLayout to TableLayout. If not you have to ask TableLayout for ChildCount, iterate over them like above, but Cast them to TableRow. then ask TableRow for Childs and recieve your Buttons.

it may be easier to call findViewById for every Button and set an onClickListener for these 10.

Yes, anything can be done in Java

Comment: Ok, interesting.  How do you apply an onclicklistener to each button. (plan on having 10 buttons with 10 sounds)

Comment: i just read your edit, want to pull my hair out and quit...but i have vowed to push forward...

Comment: and i wish i could post a screenshot, but i have to wait til my rep goes to 10

Comment: Ok, I inserted a tablelayout into my linear layout on the graphical view...then i am putting the buttons inside each row of the table layout...do i just need to change that code up there to tablelayout? or no becuase the tablelayout is inside the linearlayout?  Also, this code goes into the .java section right? and kinda unsure of where to put it in there if so...thanks for help